# Object initializer. Is it quicker than the old method?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Which is quicker and why?

```
Person person = new Person();
person.FirstName = "Scott";
person.LastName = "Guthrie";
person.Age = 32;
```

of...

```
Person person = new Person { FirstName="Scott", LastName="Guthrie", Age=32 };
```

Comment: Just guessing here, but I believe these code samples compile to the exact same code.

Comment: This is called Object initializer, I update the question title. Collection initializer is for arrays and lists.

Comment: I's not important which one is quicker.

Comment: The second is quicker (quicker to write and quicker to read, at least to me... :) )

Comment: Object initializer, although seems like a great thing at first, turns out to be a real pain during debugging. The debugger would just step through the whole initialization list in one step. I normally uses object initializer when creating anonymous classes. Otherwise I fall back to the good old assignment initializations. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 5):

This is absolutely the wrong question to be asking*. You should be asking, 'which of the following is more readable?' This sort of micro-benchmarking leads to really obscure and hard to maintain code (although maybe not in this particular situation).

- The exception is a situation where you've profiled your code and found that this construct occurs in a very hot code path. However, if you had done that, you also would have benchmarked the two methods and found out the answer for yourself :-).

Comment: Well, it's boiler-plate advice given when ever anybody asks about performance on the Internet.  It rather misses the point that the two bits of code above are the same.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the latter is syntactic sugar for the former. There should be no difference.

Comment: You are right, CLR will generate the same code.

Comment: @mt_serg Is it the CLR or the C# compiler?

Comment: @John Sorry, I mean compiler.

Comment: The C# compiler does this. The IL code ends up being exactly the same, so nothing special needs to happen at the CLR level.

Answer (score 1):

The collection initializer notation will be "expanded" to the first notation at compile time so there should be no runtime costs.